# Failed to query Roles in Public Groups

Tags: soql, roles, public-group

I have created a public group and added some roles to it. However, when I try to query the roles in that group using the following SOQL query, I am unable to do so:

SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName, RelatedId, Type FROM Group WHERE RelatedId IN (SELECT UserRoleId FROM User WHERE Id = ) AND Type = 'Regular'

**Please note**:
1.The group type is 'Regular.'
2.The 'RelatedId' field has no value in my scenario.

Additionally, there is a related list in the user object called 'Public Group Membership.' I would like to know if we can query this related list as well."

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the specific error, or describe further what "unable to do so" means regarding the results you get.